# Python defaultdict returns None on get, despite being initialized with a default value

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict

I am trying to code a variant of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. In doing that, I want to initialize the shortest path distances to `math.inf`, and have this value returned for any unseen key.

I am using a defaultdict, initialized as `defaultdict(lambda:math.inf)` with the hope of having an infinite value returned for a new key.

However, I am seeing None values being returned in the below example.

Initialization:

```py
shortest_paths = defaultdict(lambda:math.inf)
shortest_paths[k] = 0

print(f"Initial values for shortest_paths = {shortest_paths}")
```

This prints:

```
Initial values for shortest_paths = defaultdict(<function Solution.networkDelayTime.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x1044818b0>, {2: 0})
```

Call:

```py
print(f"n={n} and shortest_paths.get(n) = {shortest_paths.get(n)}")
```

This prints:

```
n=1 and shortest_paths.get(n) = None
```

This eventually leads to a comparison between the None object and an integer value, breaking my code.

```py
shortest_paths[n] = min(shortest_paths.get(n), shortest_paths.get(current) + dist)
```

Leading to:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

What I am trying to figure out is how is the value of the defaultdict not getting initialized.

This exact code pasted on the REPL is working fine. I am using VSCode, if that's relevant.

Comment: the point of `defaultdict` is you use bracketed access always -- `.get` retains its original semantics

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Please feel free to answer the question with this comment, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the point of `defaultdict` is you use bracketed access always -- `.get(...)` retains its original semantics (inherited from `dict`):

```
>>> shortest_paths = defaultdict(lambda:math.inf)
>>> shortest_paths[5]
inf
>>> shortest_paths.get(5)
inf
>>> print(shortest_paths.get(6))
None
```

Comment: why does .get(5) return an inf and .get(6) print a None I don't get it

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio: Because accessing `shortest_paths[5]` triggered `defaultdict`'s autovivification behavior (creating a key `5` with value `math.inf`). They never created `shortest_paths[6]` (explicitly by setting it, or implicitly by accessing it with brackets), so it *doesn't* exist, and `.get` returns the default for `.get` (which is `None`).